# How to only get the sign link using Docusign?

Tags: docusignapi, vtiger

I am currently working on a module for vtiger CRM where a user can sign a .PDF document using the Docusign API.

The problem I have is that I can only send an email which looks like this:
[image]

What I want is to only get an email with the security code, is that possible?

I couldn't find anything about this on their help documents.

The reason I want to do this is so that people can use their own email templates to send a signature request from within vtiger CRM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get an url for a person to sign with by using the service point `/envelopes/{envelopeId}/views/recipient`

See the [recipe](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes/signing-from-your-app).

However, you don't want to send this link in an email since the url is only good for a couple of minutes. Instead, the link sent in the email should go back to your app. Your app would then obtain the signing link and give it to the signer.

Note that by using this api call, *your app is responsible for authenticating the signer.*

This is a big deal. How does your app know that the signer is who she says she is? Logins? Exclusive control over the username/pw?

**Branding**

If what you want to do is change the look of the emails that DocuSign sends out, you can do that through the DocuSign "Branding" feature. You can change a gazillion different aspects of how the DocuSign service looks and feels to the end signers. See the [Branding manual](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/cdse-admin-guide-branding).

You can affect an account's branding through an API call or via the web app.

Comment: So it isn't possible to get the security code without making the application I am developing responsible for authenticating as well?

Comment: If the DocuSign platform sends the email, then it is doing the authentication.  If you're sending the email, then you (your app)  is responsible for the signer's authentication.  Use the branding feature to change the look of the email.